# Why are @XmlAttribute fields ignored by Swagger 1.X?

Tags: java, swagger

I have a simple model class annotated with Swagger 1.X, Jackson and JAXB annotations, such as:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "ClassA")
@ApiModel(value = "ClassA")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class ClassA
{
    @ApiModelProperty(value = "The attribute key", example = "a key")
    @XmlAttribute
    private String key;

    @ApiModelProperty(value = "The attribute name", example = "a name")
    @XmlAttribute
    private String name;

    @ApiModelProperty(value = "a value")
    @XmlElement
    private Object value;

    public String getKey()
    {
        return key;
    }

    public void setKey(String key)
    {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Object getValue()
    {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(Object value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

This is processed by CXF's [Swagger2Feature](https://cxf.apache.org/docs/swagger2feature.html) to produce a swagger.json document which is presented via Swagger-UI. CXF is at version 3.2.1, which seems to use Swagger 1.5.16.

In the generated swagger.json document, the fields annotated with @XmlAttribute are ignored (only the @XmlElement-annotated value field is included). Is there a way to make Swagger include these in the generated spec, other than changing them all to XML elements?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is a bug in the Swagger version (1.5.16) used by CXF 3.2.1 - [Swagger Core 1847](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/issues/1847). The bug was fixed in [Swagger Core 1.5.18](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/releases/tag/v1.5.18).